# how to tell gradle to build and upload archives of dependent projects to local maven

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a multi-project problem that Gradle's documentation doesn't have any info on (and can't find on stackoverflow also). Any help/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Here are my project layouts:

- project *LeftArm*:  produces a jar file
- project *RightArm*:  produces a jar file
- project *AllArms*:  depends on projects *LeftArm* and *RightArm* and produces a `war` file

When I run 'gradle build uploadArchives' in *AllArms* project, it builds *LeftArm* and *RightArm* projects but it doesn't upload the `jar` files (produced by *LeftArm* and *RightArm* projects) to local Maven repo.

Here are my `build.gradle` files:

```groovy
project LeftArm:
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

ext.artifactId = 'LeftArm'
archivesBaseName = ext.artifactId // sets filename of warfile/jarfile output
group = 'mygroup'
version = '1.0'

buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenLocal()
    }
}

jar 
{
    from(sourceSets['main'].allJava)
}

dependencies 
{
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api-sources', version:'1.0.0.GA'
}

def localRepoURL = 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath

// NOTE: this project will publish to the local Maven repo.
uploadArchives 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenDeployer 
    {
        repository(url: localRepoURL)
        addFilter('jar') 
        { 
            artifact, file -> artifact.ext == 'jar'
        }
    }
    }
}
```

...

```groovy
project RightArm:
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'

ext.artifactId = 'RightArm'
archivesBaseName = ext.artifactId // sets filename of warfile/jarfile output
group = 'mygroup'
version = '1.0'

buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenLocal()
    }
}

jar 
{
    from(sourceSets['main'].allJava)
}

dependencies 
{
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api-sources', version:'1.0.0.GA'
}

def localRepoURL = 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath

// NOTE: this project will publish to the local Maven repo.
uploadArchives 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenDeployer 
    {
        repository(url: localRepoURL)
        addFilter('jar') 
        { 
            artifact, file -> artifact.ext == 'jar'
        }
    }
    }
}
```

...

```groovy
project AllArms:
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

ext.artifactId = 'AllArms'
ext.sourceCompatibility = 1.6
archivesBaseName = artifactId // sets filename of warfile/jarfile output
group = 'mygroup'
version = '1.0'

def gwtVersion = '2.2.0'

repositories
{
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies
{
    compile project(':LeftArm') 
    compile project(':RightArm') 
    // ###   NOTE:  this is where the build breaks b/c uploadArchives task is not executed  ###
    compile group: group, name: 'LeftArm', version:version
    compile group: group, name: 'RightArm', version:version
    providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.validation', name:'validation-api-sources', version:'1.0.0.GA'
    providedCompile group: 'com.google.gwt', name:'gwt-user', version:gwtVersion
    providedCompile group: 'com.google.gwt', name:'gwt-dev', version:gwtVersion
    providedCompile group: 'org.gwtext', name:'gwtext', version:'2.0.4'
}

task compileGwt (dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    project.ext 
    {
    gwtDir = "${project.buildDir}/gwt"
    extraDir = "${project.buildDir}/extra"
    gwtModuleName = 'MyModuleName'
    }
    inputs.source sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    inputs.dir sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir
    outputs.dir project.gwtDir

    // Workaround for incremental build (GRADLE-1483)
    outputs.upToDateSpec = new org.gradle.api.specs.AndSpec()

    doFirst
    {
    file(project.gwtDir).mkdirs()
    }

    main = 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler'

    classpath
    {
    [
        sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,           // Java source
        sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir,    // Generated resources
        sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,      // Generated classes
        sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,       // Deps
    ]
    }

    args =
    [
    project.gwtModuleName, // Your GWT module
    '-war', project.gwtDir,
    '-logLevel', 'INFO',
    '-localWorkers', '2',
    '-compileReport',
    '-extra', project.extraDir,
    ]

    maxHeapSize = '256M'
}

buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenLocal()
    }
}

sourceSets 
{
    main 
    {
    resources 
    {           srcDir('src/main/java').include('**/client/**').include('**/public/**').include('**/*.gwt.xml')
    }
    }
}

war.dependsOn(compileGwt)
war 
{
    def gwtOutputTree = project.fileTree(project.gwtDir)
    from(gwtOutputTree)
    baseName = artifactId
}

task classesJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn(classes)
    baseName = artifactId
}

artifacts 
{
    archives war, classesJar
}

def localRepoURL = 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath

// NOTE: this project will publish to the local Maven repo.
uploadArchives 
{
    repositories 
    {
    mavenDeployer 
    {
        repository(url: localRepoURL)

        addFilter('war') 
        { 
            artifact, file -> artifact.ext == 'war'
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: instead of hard-coding the local repo url: `repository(url: mavenLocal().url)`

Answer (score 5):

`uploadArchives` isn't meant to be used to install to the local Maven repository. Instead, use the `install` task.

Comment: From within project AllArms, I ran 'gradle build install' and it doesn't publish/upload/install LeftArm and RightArm jars. Any other suggestions ? Thanks for responding.

Comment: You need to run the `install` task for each project that you want to have installed. Typically, this is achieved by running `gradle install` for a parent project. By the way, `compile group: group, name: 'LeftArm', version:version` doesn't make sense because there is already a project dependency on `LeftArm`. Same for `RightArm`. Also note that the only good reason to publish to the local Maven repo and to declare `mavenLocal()` is for exchanging artifacts with Maven builds.

Comment: I agree w/you on that compile line. I had it there initially as a copy/paste remnant, which then uncovers the issue of dependent projects are not installed to local Maven repo. I need to update local Maven repo b/c that repo will be tarred and sent to my client when they build our codes in their env using Maven. I do have settings.gradle to define all the Gradle projects. The issue with running gradle install on each project is we'll hook up to Jenkins automated build and that will kick off the build at the top most project (not each individual sub-projects).

Comment: Are you saying that there's no way for me to run a gradle command on a top level project that will upload/publish all the sub/dependent projects to my local Maven repo ?

Comment: The install tasks aren't dependent on each other, but if you run `gradle install` for the root project, the `install` tasks for all three subprojects will be run. This feature is called *name-matching execution*.

Comment: That's good to know. Using that same logic, if I run gradle uploadArchives, wouldn't all three uploadArchives execute also ? That doesn't seem to be happening. The reason I use uploadArchives is some projects produce jar and war artifacts, while others only produce just a jar or a war file.

Comment: It works for any task. In any case, `uploadArchives` is the wrong choice for installing to the local Maven repo.

Comment: When I use install task, I get the following error b/c my AllArms project produces a jar and a war (any ideas for how to get around that?): Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > A POM can not have multiple main artifacts. ...

Comment: You can configure the `install` task in a similar way as `uploadArchives`. For an example, search the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for `mavenInstaller`.

Comment: I was able to get the install task to work (not get the POM error message) with the following configuration:  install
{
    repositories 
    {
        mavenInstaller 
        {
            addFilter('war') 
            { 
                artifact, file -> artifact.ext == 'war'
            }

            addFilter('jar') 
            { 
                artifact, file -> artifact.ext == 'jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
Thanks for the help on that. I still can't get subprojects to install to local Maven. Still more work to be done. Thanks again for all your help.